# How do I install VLC into raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc, vlc

I've recently installed raspbmc into a Raspberry Pi v2, which has an external hard drive hooked up through a USB hub. When I boot the Raspberry PI, I can navigate to the hard drive and see couple of `*.ISO` files store there.

My experience with unix commands is limited, so I need detailed help on how to install VLC and set it up in such a way so that when I launch the `*.ISO` files, the VLC launches and plays the `*.ISO` files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say `.iso` files. Do you mean OS's, or simply random disk images? Also, there is no such thing as a `Raspberry Pi v2`, are you talking about the model b or a?

Answer (score 4):

**Basics**

1. First off, you need to install the `vlc` [package](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6835/6609).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vlc
   ```

   You should see a few things show up on the terminal, and then a `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?` Click `Y`.
2. Next, you need to make `VLC` the default application to open these types of files. `Right-Click` on one of your .iso files. Click on `Properties`. Then go to `Open with:` and select `VLC`.
3. If the above did not work, you can always open these files manually. Go into the console, and type `VLC`. A window should pop up. In the toolbar select `Media > Open File` and navigate to the desired `.ISO`.

**OMXPlayer Alternative**

If you don't like VLC, you can use the GPU accelerated omxplayer. Below is a link on Github.

https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer#readme

**Learn more**

I have compiled a set of links. They will give you more information about this topic.

[Is it possible to install VLC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/667/6609)

[How to create a VLC playlist at startup](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=17051)